# Binding Autocompletebox to Datagrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Hello I'm very new to WPF and binding, still trying to get the Hang of it. Currently I have a Datagrid bind to my ObservableCollections, But Now I want to bind my Autocompletebox to a column of the Datagrids but it's not binding correctly. If I may get some guidance to how to Display PaymentNo from the Datagrid into Autocompletebox that would be greatly appreciated.

Think this may be the only Code needed

```
for (int iIndex = 1; iIndex <= totalpayments; ++iIndex)
        {
            PaymentInfo paymentInfo = new PaymentInfo();
            paymentInfo.PaymentNo = iIndex;
            paymentInfo.Date = date.AddMonths(iIndex);
            paymentInfo.Balance = Math.Round(CalculateBalance(iIndex), 2);
            paymentInfo.Payment = Math.Round(Payment, 2);   
            paymentInfo.Interest = Math.Round(CalculateInterestPart(iIndex), 2);
            paymentInfo.Principle = Math.Round(CalculatePrinciple(iIndex), 2);
            Payments.Add(paymentInfo);
        }
```

On the Xaml Side

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Payments.PaymentNo}"/>
```

I believe it has to do with `ItemsSource="{Binding Payments.PaymentNo}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}" DisplayMemberPath="PaymentNo" TextSearchPath="PaymentNo"/>
```

Key is `TextSearchPath` which according to [telerik docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/properties_t_telerik_windows_controls_radautocompletebox.html) will filter "The name or path of the property that is used when filtering for each the data item in the control."

Comment: Thanks bud! for the help